# .Net core session issue with StackExchangeRedis on multiple instances

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redis, cloud, cloud-foundry

We have a .Net core 6 project deployed to multiple instances on PCF (Pivotal cloud foundry). We use Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis 6.0 and StackExchange.Redis 2.6.66

The problem is when only has one instance, everything is working. But when on multiple instances, session is null.

Below is our code in startup.cs.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache()
  services.AddSession()
  services.AddControllers()
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  app.UseSession();
  app.UseEndpoints();
}
```

This project is migrated from .net framework, so we also have AppHttpContext which has a static IHttpContextAccessor and a Current method.

Then `AppHttpContext.ContextAccessor = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredServices\<IHttpContextAccessor\>();`

Just wondering what is missing. Why session is null?

We tried with just one instance, it worked. When having two instances, we can see Redis have keys from both instances. But somehow session is null. Feel like reading from Redis is not right. Key from one instance is not read by another instance. We cannot/not allowed config network that when user is logged in always send the following requests to the same instance.

update: see this exception:
Error unprotecting the session cookie.
The key [] was not found in the key ring.

Comment: Turned out default cookie name has to be JSESSIONID. Or modify PCF config for customized cookie name. But it is still sticky session solution. With the info Tim provided below, we used Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.StackExchangeRedis to implement. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the missing piece is that you haven't configured [DataProtection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/introduction?view=aspnetcore-6.0) (basically each app instance is probably using a different key for storing session info). You might be interested in some additional reading on [sharing cookies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Have you considered adding [Steeltoe](https://steeltoe.io) to the mix in your application? One of the reasons it was originally created was to make it easier to run .NET apps on Cloud Foundry (specifically PCF), and it does include [a package](https://docs.steeltoe.io/api/v3/security/redis-key-storage-provider.html) to help with scenarios just like this.

You don't mention anything about how you're dealing with service bindings or if you're using the SSO tile, but Steeltoe can help with those too. Samples in [this location](https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Samples/tree/main/Security), most notably [this class](https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Samples/blob/main/Security/src/CloudFoundrySingleSignon/Startup.cs#L31) should get you started on solving this issue.

You can also find some related information in the [Tanzu .NET Cookbook](https://tanzu.vmware.com/developer/cookbooks/dotnet/)

Comment: Worked! Thanks for the info. We used Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.StackExchangeRedis.